# Meteor each loop loading takes so much time

Tags: javascript, meteor

Meteor each loop data taking too much time to load. While its loading displays stop script error. Please help me how to solve this issue. Please find the code.

```
{{#each list_data}}
    <optgroup label="{{ desc }}">
        {{#each arr}}
            {{#if isSelected material_id ../material_id}}
                <option value="{{material_id}}"  id="{{ material_id }}" selected> {{description}} </option>
            {{else}}
                <option value="{{ material_id }}" id="{{ material_id }}"> {{ description }} </option>
            {{/if}}
        {{/each}}
    </optgroup>
{{/each}}

Template.list.isSelected = function(fooToCheck, recordFoo)
{
    if(recordFoo == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return (fooToCheck == recordFoo);
    }
};
```

Comment: Could you please show us what you have tried so far in optimizing this?

Comment: Not implemented any thing right now. @JohnOdom

Comment: I think we'd need to see an example of the document that list_data represents, and how many of them there are. Also maybe the pub/sub ?

Answer (score 0):

If indeed there a lot of objects being retrieved you may consider using reactive vars - check the meteor docs.